# Catching an exception while using a Python 'with' statement

Tags: python, exception

I can't figure out how to handle exception for python 'with' statement. If I have a code:

```
with open("a.txt") as f:
    print f.readlines()
```

I really want to handle 'file not found exception' in order to do something. But I can't write

```
with open("a.txt") as f:
    print f.readlines()
except:
    print 'oops'
```

and can't write

```
with open("a.txt") as f:
    print f.readlines()
else:
    print 'oops'
```

Enclosing `with` in a try/except statement doesn't work either, and an exception is not raised. What can I do in order to process failure inside `with` statement in a Pythonic way?

Comment: What do you mean *"enclosing 'with' in a try/except statement doesn't work else: exception is not raised"*? A `with` statement doesn't magically break a surrounding `try...except` statement.

Comment: Interestingly, Java's try-with-resources statement *does* support exactly this use case you want. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Perhaps this wasn't possible in older versions of Python, but for 3.8, it seems putting `with` in the `try` statement does allow it to handle `except FileNotFoundError`

Answer (score 350, accepted):

This solution will keep the with-block-code outside of the try-except-clause.

```
try:
    f = open('foo.txt')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('error')
else:
    with f:
        print f.readlines()
```

Comment: Will the file get closed in this example? I ask because it was opened outside of the "with" scope.

Comment: @MikeCollins Exiting the 'with' will close the open file even when the file is open before the 'with'.

Comment: You have to use `finally` in 2nd example to close the file

Comment: @Superior No, you do not. If the open succeeds, you will enter the with-clause in any case, which will close the file.—If it fails, well, the file is not open to begin with.

Answer (score 107):

The best "Pythonic" way to do this, exploiting the `with` statement, is listed as Example #6 in [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), which gives the background of the statement.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def opened_w_error(filename, mode="r"):
    try:
        f = open(filename, mode)
    except IOError, err:
        yield None, err
    else:
        try:
            yield f, None
        finally:
            f.close()
```

Used as follows:

```
with opened_w_error("/etc/passwd", "a") as (f, err):
    if err:
        print "IOError:", err
    else:
        f.write("guido::0:0::/:/bin/sh\n")
```

Comment: I like it but it feels like a little too much black magic. Its not entirely explicit for the reader

Comment: @PaulSeeb Why wouldn't you define it and save yourself from doing it each time you need to? It's defined at your application level, and it's as magic as any other contextmanager. I think someone using the with statement would understand it clearly (the name of the function might also be more expressive if you don't like it). The "with" statement itself has been engineered to work this way, to define a "secure" block of code and delegate checking functions to context managers (to make the code more clear).

Comment: All this trouble just for not writing the finally block in the user code. I'm beginning to think we all suffer for a long hype symptom on the with statement.

Comment: The best way to handle exceptions in python is to write a function that catches and returns them? Seriously? The pythonic way to handle exceptions is to use a `try...except` statement.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you!  It's the only answer that doesn't violate the rule against having more than 1 line in a try statement and that also allows me to keep the with statement instead of opening and closing the connection separately.

Comment: It feels to me like something I'd do in Go or Rust. Interesting. If I was the BDFL (and given what I know to this point), I'd be all for adding `with/except` to the Python language, though. @Aran-Fey I wouldn't worry too much about "one line under a try" rule. If the possible exceptions can be sensibly attributed, it is IMO perfectly fine to have more lines. It just requires that after any further code modifications the result is always reconsidered with an open mind.

Answer (score 82):

> ### Catching an exception while using a Python 'with' statement

The with statement has been available without the `__future__` import [since Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html). You can get it as [early as Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) (but at this point it's time to upgrade!) with:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

Here's the closest thing to correct that you have. You're almost there, but `with` doesn't have an `except` clause:

> ```
> with open("a.txt") as f: 
>     print(f.readlines())
> except:                    # <- with doesn't have an except clause.
>     print('oops')
> ```

A context manager's `__exit__` method, if it returns `False` will reraise the error when it finishes. If it returns `True`, it will suppress it. The `open` builtin's `__exit__` doesn't return `True`, so you just need to nest it in a try, except block:

```
try:
    with open("a.txt") as f:
        print(f.readlines())
except Exception as error: 
    print('oops')
```

And standard boilerplate: don't use a bare `except:` which catches `BaseException` and every other possible exception and warning. Be at least as specific as `Exception`, and for this error, perhaps catch `IOError`. Only catch errors you're prepared to handle.

So in this case, you'd do:

```
>>> try:
...     with open("a.txt") as f:
...         print(f.readlines())
... except IOError as error: 
...     print('oops')
... 
oops
```

Comment: You cannot use `f` in the except statements to somehow "correct" the behavior since you're out of the context where it was created. (In my case I'm catching a warning and solve the related issue in the `except` block).
To achieve this, I think only reimplementing a context manager like in @user765144 's answer does the job.

Answer (score 18):

## Differentiating between the possible origins of exceptions raised from a compound `with` statement

Differentiating between exceptions that occur in a `with` statement is tricky because they can originate in different places. Exceptions can be raised from either of the following places (or functions called therein):

- `ContextManager.__init__`
- `ContextManager.__enter__`
- the body of the `with`
- `ContextManager.__exit__`

For more details see the documentation about [Context Manager Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types).

If we want to distinguish between these different cases, just wrapping the `with` into a `try .. except` is not sufficient. Consider the following example (using `ValueError` as an example but of course it could be substituted with any other exception type):

```
try:
    with ContextManager():
        BLOCK
except ValueError as err:
    print(err)
```

Here the `except` will catch exceptions originating in all of the four different places and thus does not allow to distinguish between them. If we move the instantiation of the context manager object outside the `with`, we can distinguish between `__init__` and `BLOCK / __enter__ / __exit__`:

```
try:
    mgr = ContextManager()
except ValueError as err:
    print('__init__ raised:', err)
else:
    try:
        with mgr:
            try:
                BLOCK
            except TypeError:  # catching another type (which we want to handle here)
                pass
    except ValueError as err:
        # At this point we still cannot distinguish between exceptions raised from
        # __enter__, BLOCK, __exit__ (also BLOCK since we didn't catch ValueError in the body)
        pass
```

Effectively this just helped with the `__init__` part but we can add an extra sentinel variable to check whether the body of the `with` started to execute (i.e. differentiating between `__enter__` and the others):

```
try:
    mgr = ContextManager()  # __init__ could raise
except ValueError as err:
    print('__init__ raised:', err)
else:
    try:
        entered_body = False
        with mgr:
            entered_body = True  # __enter__ did not raise at this point
            try:
                BLOCK
            except TypeError:  # catching another type (which we want to handle here)
                pass
    except ValueError as err:
        if not entered_body:
            print('__enter__ raised:', err)
        else:
            # At this point we know the exception came either from BLOCK or from __exit__
            pass
```

The tricky part is to differentiate between exceptions originating from `BLOCK` and `__exit__` because an exception that escapes the body of the `with` will be passed to `__exit__` which can decide how to handle it (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__exit__)). If however `__exit__` raises itself, the original exception will be replaced by the new one. To deal with these cases we can add a general `except` clause in the body of the `with` to store any potential exception that would have otherwise escaped unnoticed and compare it with the one caught in the outermost `except` later on - if they are the same this means the origin was `BLOCK` or otherwise it was `__exit__` (in case `__exit__` suppresses the exception by returning a true value the outermost `except` will simply not be executed).

```
try:
    mgr = ContextManager()  # __init__ could raise
except ValueError as err:
    print('__init__ raised:', err)
else:
    entered_body = exc_escaped_from_body = False
    try:
        with mgr:
            entered_body = True  # __enter__ did not raise at this point
            try:
                BLOCK
            except TypeError:  # catching another type (which we want to handle here)
                pass
            except Exception as err:  # this exception would normally escape without notice
                # we store this exception to check in the outer `except` clause
                # whether it is the same (otherwise it comes from __exit__)
                exc_escaped_from_body = err
                raise  # re-raise since we didn't intend to handle it, just needed to store it
    except ValueError as err:
        if not entered_body:
            print('__enter__ raised:', err)
        elif err is exc_escaped_from_body:
            print('BLOCK raised:', err)
        else:
            print('__exit__ raised:', err)
```

## Alternative approach using the equivalent form mentioned in PEP 343

[PEP 343 -- The "with" Statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement) specifies an equivalent "non-with" version of the `with` statement. Here we can readily wrap the various parts with `try ... except` and thus differentiate between the different potential error sources:

```
import sys

try:
    mgr = ContextManager()
except ValueError as err:
    print('__init__ raised:', err)
else:
    try:
        value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
    except ValueError as err:
        print('__enter__ raised:', err)
    else:
        exit = type(mgr).__exit__
        exc = True
        try:
            try:
                BLOCK
            except TypeError:
                pass
            except:
                exc = False
                try:
                    exit_val = exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info())
                except ValueError as err:
                    print('__exit__ raised:', err)
                else:
                    if not exit_val:
                        raise
        except ValueError as err:
            print('BLOCK raised:', err)
        finally:
            if exc:
                try:
                    exit(mgr, None, None, None)
                except ValueError as err:
                    print('__exit__ raised:', err)
```

## Usually a simpler approach will do just fine

The need for such special exception handling should be quite rare and normally wrapping the whole `with` in a `try ... except` block will be sufficient. Especially if the various error sources are indicated by different (custom) exception types (the context managers need to be designed accordingly) we can readily distinguish between them. For example:

```
try:
    with ContextManager():
        BLOCK
except InitError:  # raised from __init__
    ...
except AcquireResourceError:  # raised from __enter__
    ...
except ValueError:  # raised from BLOCK
    ...
except ReleaseResourceError:  # raised from __exit__
    ...
```

Comment: "the context managers need to be designed accordingly" - Ah yeah that's the catch. It seems that no-one does that.

Answer (score 2):

This is the recommendation from the [contextlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#reentrant-cms) for Python 3:

```py
from contextlib import ExitStack

stack = ExitStack()
try:
    f = stack.enter_context(open("a.txt"))
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("oops")
else:
    with stack:
        f.readlines()
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this in a program I made:

```
try:
    with open(os.path.join(basedir, "rules.txt")) as f:
        self.rules.setText(f.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    self.rules.setText("Sorry, unable to read rules")
```

Comment: self.rules.setText("Sorry, unable to read rules") is on a new line. SO didn't show it.

Comment: so is the except part too