# Catch exception happening during Context Manager - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using python “with” statement with try-except block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642080/using-python-with-statement-with-try-except-block)

I'm using `open` to open a file in Python. I encapsulate the file handling in a `with` statement as such:

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    # do something with f
    # this part might throw an exception
```

This way I am sure my file is closed, even though an exception is thrown.

However, I would like to handle the case where opening the file fails (an `OSError` is thrown).
One way to do this would be put the whole `with` block in a `try:`. This works as long as the file handling code does not throw a OSError.

It could look something like :

```
try:
   with open(path, 'rb') as f:
except:
   #error handling
       # Do something with the file
```

This of course does not work and is really ugly. Is there a smart way of doing this ?

Thanks

PS: I'm using python 3.3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open the file first, then use it as a context manager:

```
try:
   f = open(path, 'rb')
except IOError:
   # Handle exception

with f:
    # other code, `f` will be closed at the end.
```

Comment: @paul: Then accept this answer (and up-vote it too if you think it's worthy).

Comment: here f will b out of scope . .I.e with cannot access 'f'

Comment: @SandeepDas: I've assumed that handling the request means you'll exit the function or otherwise not continue with using `f` as a context manager. You can use an `else:` block here (part of the `try:` statement) if you are not exiting.