# How do I read in a text file in python 3.3.3 and store it in a variable?

Tags: file-io, python-3.x, python-unicode

How do I read in a text file in python 3.3.3 and store it in a variable? I'm struggling with this unicode coming from python 2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this file:

```
utf-8:   áèíöû
```

This works as you expect (*IFF utf-8 is your default encoding*):

```
with open('/tmp/unicode.txt') as f:
    variable=f.read()

print(variable)
```

It is better to explicitly state your intensions if you are unsure what the default is by using a keyword argument to [open](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#open):

```
with open('/tmp/unicode.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    variable=f.read()
```

The keyword [encodings supported](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/codecs.html#id3) are in the codec module. (For Python 2, you need to use codecs [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) to open the file rather than Python 2's [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) BTW.)

Comment: You don't need to use 'with' and 'as'. You can just use 'f = open(args)'

Comment: In this case true, but using `with` is a good habit. Consider the differences of using `open` and catching the exception and `read` and then catching a different exception. Using `with` as a matter of habit allows more straight forward `try/except` blocks to be added. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642080/using-python-with-statement-with-try-except-block) and [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)