# Catch exception throw from inside of the with statement

Tags: python

```
zip_file_name = "not_exist.py"

try:
   with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name) as f_handle:
       print("open it successfully")
except (zipfile.BadZipfile, zipfile.LargeZipFile), e:
       print(e)
```

Is this the correct way to handle exception throw by a with statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching an exception while using a Python 'with' statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713794/catching-an-exception-while-using-a-python-with-statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is how you would want to handle exceptions from inside a `with` statement. ContextManagers (that implement the behavior behind the `with` statement) *can* handle exceptions but should only do so to properly clean up resources used by the object.

Here's a snippet from the [relevant documentation](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#writing-context-managers):

> If BLOCK raises an exception, the context manager’s **exit**() method
>   is called with three arguments, the exception details (type, value,
>   traceback, the same values returned by sys.exc_info(), which can also
>   be None if no exception occurred). The method’s return value controls
>   whether an exception is re-raised: any false value re-raises the
>   exception, and True will result in suppressing it. You’ll only rarely
>   want to suppress the exception, because if you do the author of the
>   code containing the ‘with‘ statement will never realize anything went
>   wrong.

Comment: While that is correct, it's not the full story. That documentation refers to exceptions coming from the BLOCK part of the with statement. It is *not* applicable to exceptions from the expression that returns the ContextManager. If you look at the types of exceptions the OP is catching, it seems that the OP is  interested in the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's fine.

Another alternative is:

```
try:
   f_handle = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name)
   # no more code here
except (zipfile.BadZipfile, zipfile.LargeZipFile), e:
   print(e)
else:
   with f_handle:
      print("open it successfully")
```

This prevents you from accidentally catching an exception from the body of the `with` statement in your `except` handler.

Comment: This won't give the ZipFile a chance to cleanup ( the `__exit__` portion of the ContextManager ) if an exception occurs after resources have been acquired. If you're going to go down this route, I suggest using try/except/finally instead.

Comment: @Chris Phillips: Hmm.... What exceptions can occur between the assignment succeeding and the with statement being called?

Comment: @Mark, I guess that Chris had made assumption that more code can be added following the assignment statement. I have made a comment in your code and see it works for him.