# Why can't the with statement have an except clause

Tags: python, exception, with-statement

Trying to understand exception handling and the with statement, I'm curious if anyone understand why the design of python is such that the following code (following the "naive" question in [1]) is illegal:

```
with open("a.txt") as f:
    print f.readlines()
except IOError:
    print 'Oops, failed to open the file'
```

Wouldn't it be a good idea to have the "with" statement also serve as an implicit "try" statement when an "except" clause is present at the appropriate indentation level? Though "with" blocks are about resources that need to be released when an exception occurs within the block, resource allocation is always fertile ground for exceptions to occur. It's not always silly to handle exceptions close to where they occur.

One of the answers to [1] mention the most-pythonic way to get this effect, using contextmanagers. But wouldn't the above be clearer and shorter, even more pythonic?

[1] [Catching an exception while using a Python 'with' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713794/catching-an-exception-while-using-a-python-with-statement)

Comment: Note that your question is really not suited to the Stack Overflow Q&A format; although I can state my opinion about the philosophy of the `with` statement with conviction, it is still *opinion* and *conjucture* best left to the Python development lists, not to this site. See the [FAQ].

Comment: In fact, this came up on the `python-idea` list a while ago. It was rejected (or, more accurately, didn't gather much support and died off).

Comment: it's also confusing, it looks like the `except` applies to the body of the `with`, not the `with` line itself

Answer (score 4):

The context manager is passed the exception, and can handle that exception like an `except` block in a `try` `except` combo can.

Adding a `except` suite to the `with` block would confuse matters; the responsibility would then be split between the context manager and that block.