# with operator inside try-except

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
with open("a.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    # operation on data
```

This will close the file `a.txt` if there is any Error on my operations on data. I wanted to know, what if the file `a.txt` doesn't exist.
Should my code be:

```
try:
    with open("a.txt") as f:
        data = f.read()
        # operation on data
except IOError:
    print "No such File"
```

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713794/catching-an-exception-while-using-a-python-with-statement

You can use an environment error

Comment: You can use a passive `try/except` without a specific error.

Comment: The with-expression is a fancy way to trigger a background mechanism that wraps the code inside into a try/finally. You can add addition try/except/finally statements, inside and outside the with-block.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, a bare try/except is never a good idea

Answer (score 0):

If the file does not exist unless you use the `try/except` an error will be raised, if the file does not exist nothing will be opened so there will be nothing to close. if you want to catch when the file does not exist you need to use the try.

If you want to output a message based on the type of error you can check the errno:

```
try:
    with open("a.txt") as f:
       data = f.read()
except IOError as e:
    if e.errno == 2:
        print("No such File")
```

If you want to create the file if it does not exist or else read from it you can use `a+`:

```
with open("a.txt","a+") as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path` to verify the existence of a file path, for example:

```
if os.path.exists('data.txt'):
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
        # do stuff with file here
```

Comment: EAFP vs LBYL, isn't it more pythonic to EAFP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092992/why-is-it-easier-to-ask-forgiveness-than-permission-in-python-but-not-in-java. You still may have a race condition where is does exist for the if but not the open...