# How to close file while using with and try..except?

Tags: python

I wrote this example to show myself that `__exit__` is not being run when an exception occurs:

```
class A(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print('enter')
    def __exit__(self):
        print('exit')
try:
    with A() as a:
        raise RunTimeError()
except Exception as e:
    print('except')
```

Output:

```
enter
except
```

That said, what is the correct way to use a `with` statement and catch exceptions, while making sure `__exit__` is being run in the end?
Thanks!

Comment: The errors first pass through `__exit__` your `__exit__` functions needs to have parameters `exc_type, exc_value, traceback` (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__).

Comment: maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713794/catching-an-exception-while-using-a-python-with-statement

Comment: Can you swap the `try` and `with` clauses order?

Comment: Thanks Willem, that's the answer... My bad!

Comment: Now that's strange: As-is, `exit` is not called, but if I change it to `exit(self, *args)`, it is called (as suggested by @WillemVanOnsem). BUT if I swap the order of `with` and `try`, such that (in my understanding) the `try` should handle the exception without ever bothering the surrounding `with`, then it complains about `exit` having the wrong number of arguments. Why does it only complain about missing arguments then?

Comment: BTW, that code does not actually raise a `RuntimeError` but a `NameError` :-P

Comment: @tobias_k: `__exit__` is called, but it results in a `TypeError` (since the  parameters do not match) and that type error is then handled in the `except` block.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah, of course, that makes sense. Lesson learned: Never just print "except" without showing the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`__exit__` function is called**, regardless whether the `with` body raises errors or not. Your function needs to have additional parameters `exc_type` (the type of the exception), `exc_value` (the exception object), and `traceback` (the traceback that is generated).

In case the `with` body did *not* raise an `Error`, the three parameters are `None`. In case there is an error, they take the values described above.

But you can for instance close a file, regardless whether there is an error and then later handle the error.

So we can here implement it for instance as:

```
class A(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.file = open('some_file.txt')
        return self.file

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print(('exit', exc_type, exc_value, traceback))
        # close the file, regardless of exceptions
        self.file.close()
        return False  # silence the exception?
```

If we now write something like:

```
with A():
    raise Exception
```

We will obtain the exception, the `__exit__` function will print:

```
('exit', <class 'Exception'>, Exception(), <traceback object at 0x7fc512c924c8>)
```

We can inspect the exception class, exception value and traceback, and handle accordingly. For instance based on the exception, we might decide to close a file, send a bug report, abort the SQL transaction or not.

The `__exit__` function also has a return value (if not specified, a Python function returns `None`). In case the `__exit__` function returns an object with *truthiness* `True`, it will *surpress* the exception: the exception will not raise out of the `with` block. Otherwise it will be raised out of the `with` block. For instance in our example, we still receive the exception.

```
class SilenceExceptions(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        return True  # silence ALL exceptions
```

If we now call:

```
with SilenceExceptions():
    raise Error
```

we will not see the exception, since it is "*catched*" in the `__exit__` function.

Comment: Thanks. That said, would you say, in this case, that my try-with structure is the correct and usual way of doing this? (And not, for example, with the try-with order reversed)?

Comment: That depends whether you want to catch exceptions *within* the block. For instance if you process a file, and you want to ignore the lines that fail to parse, the `try:` should be placed in the `with:` (and in a `for` loop in the `with`). In case you want to close the context if the error raises, then it is common to place the `with` in the `try`. Since you then offer the context amanger the change to solve the problem at context level.