# Pickle is not saving data to a file with a formatted string name

Tags: python, pickle

I am baffled by the behavior of the code below. There are two problems; I am not sure whether they are related in some strange way.

The first problem is the more important one. The code should save two files containing the same data. However, `test.pkl` is about 79 kB whereas the other is empty. Why is nothing being saved there after the file is created?

The second issue I noticed is that the second file is saved as something like `e-v-w1-n2-2020-12-13-19` without any file extension. What happened to the `.pkl`?

I am using Python 3.8 with pickle 4.0 on Windows 10.

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import datetime

n = 100
z = np.zeros((n,n))
with open("test.pkl" , 'wb') as myfile:
    pickle.dump(z, myfile)

filename = "e-v-w%s-n%s-%s.pkl" % (1, 2, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M"))
print(filename)
with open(filename, "wb") as outfile:
    pickle.dump(z, outfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

When I print `filename`, the `.pkl` appears as it should, by the way.

Comment: Step by step debug and exception catch would have told you what was the issue. It is a worthy ritual to adopt when developing, before going to SO.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of that, as I've never really used one before. Following your comment, I just learned how to use the basic functions of `pdb`. However, there is something I do not understand - how would an exception catch have helped here? The code ran to completion without throwing any errors.

Comment: See 2nd answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713794/catching-an-exception-while-using-a-python-with-statement

Comment: Thank you - so if I understand, there is an error in the `with` statement that we can catch, but Python doesn't stop executing the code (just the `with` block) for it. Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon character (":") is not allowed in Windows filepaths, for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename).

Your `strftime` format includes a colon, which makes it impossible for that path to be written to, and is also presumably the reason why the characters after the colon (suck as the `.pkl` extension) are missing.

Running your code on a Unix platform worked as expected. Simply change your `strftime` format to make it compatible with Windows.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it. Yes, the second call with the formatted string was from a code that had previously been run on Unix, and I had missed the colon when rereading the code.