# 'consider-using-with' code quality suggestion from VS Code using subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

I used subprocess.popen as follows. The following linter suggestion occurs in vscode

```
try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(
                ["python", "app.py"]
            )
except:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

```
Consider using 'with' for resource-allocating operationspylint(consider-using-with)
```

But I don't know where to use 'with'

Comment: That's not an error. It's a suggestion.

Comment: Where do you put 'with' to accept the suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `with` to assign the variable from `subprocess.popen()`.

```
try:
    with subprocess.Popen(['python', 'app.py']) as p:
        # code here
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Note that the `try/except` will also catch exceptions in the body of `with`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/713814/1491895) for how you can structure the code to just catch an exception from `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: Won't this make the subprocess blocking?

Comment: If `subprocess.Popen()` blocks, it will block in either version.

Comment: But it doesn't block, and using `with` won't make it blocking.

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation that says that the context manager blocks.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but at the end of this section: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

_Popen objects are supported as context managers via the with statement: on exit, standard file descriptors are closed, and the process is waited for._

Comment: That's on *exit*, not when it starts.

Comment: I see your appoint. The advice assumes that you're going to process all the output of the subprocess, so you'll eventually wait for the process to exit. All that code should be inside the `with`.

Comment: So my real question I guess is: if we want to launch an independent process (one for which we don't want to wait that it exits), we cannot use a context manager? Therefore, our only hope to satisfy pylint is to disable the warning?

Comment: Of course. In general you only use a context manager when you're using the resource within a local context.

Comment: You shouldn't disable the warning globally, use a comment to suppress it for that call.

Comment: This doesn't work, I wanted to remove an error `consider-using-with` but now my process is blocking.

Comment: It's not an error, it's just a style warning. And it's not appropriate if you need to use the resource more dynamically than a context manager allows. So you should suppress it when it doesn't fit your use.